# Slow performance when querying remote db - is this normal?

Tags: .net, database, performance

I am doing some loading from an oracle db, using ODP.NET.

In its current implementation the code does something along the lines of:

```
query entityIds to load based on criteria  
    foreach entityId
        load attributes 
        query geometries that exist
        foreach geometry that exists
            load geometry
        next
    next
```

when the DB is on the local network criteria which load 133 entities takes a couple of seconds to load all 133 entities.

When the db is a remote db hosted on a VM in a data center on the other side of the world this takes about 3.5 mins to load them all.

The particularly slow bit seems to be the querying the geometry.  In initial testing (in TOAD - not in the service loading code) it seems to take about 2 secs to load the geometry for a single entity using the remote machine.  If we change the query to load all the geometries in a single go, it still seems to take 2 secs.  This sort of implies that it isn't the network overhead (as the amount of data being returned is much more for the query which returns all the geometries, but the time is the same).

Is this sort of performance overhead for a remote db vs local expected?  Why does doing each query separately take so much longer than doing them all in one go?  Is there anything we can do to mitigate this (apart from do all the queries in one go)?

Comment: For each of those "load X" statements in your pseudo-code, are you executing SQL?

Comment: And when you say that "it still seems to take 2 secs", to load all the entitites or per entity? You say the amount of data is the same, surely the amount of data for all the entitites can't be the same as the amount of data for one? You need to specify more where those 2 seconds come into play. Per entity? or total?

Comment: Your application design is terrible (if all those entites are in the same db and load means `select * from...`. Try something more like "load entities, attributes and geometries based on criteria" using a single sql statment that takes advantage of joins

Comment: @Lasse - yes a stored procedure (or more than 1) is executed in each of the "load X" statements, and the times were for loading a single entity or all the entities.  I will edit to clarify.

Comment: @BenCr, thanks I understand that, I'm just trying to figure out if there is a simple way to improve my local performance (I'm remote, others are local) as the tests take about 10 mins to run for me and a few seconds for the others, without changing the way things work significantly.  We know this is an area which needs work, but we are not at a stage where we can do that work yet, due to other pressures.

Comment: @Sam I suggest you take a copy of your database and host it locally or run your tests remotely (using cruise control or TFS or something) until you can resolve your design issues. Depending how often you run the tests it sounds like you could use the time you're wasting waiting for them to run to fix the design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably coming up on the distinction between bandwidth and latency.

Latency is the time taken for a single round-trip, whereas bandwidth is the amount of data that can flow through over a given time period (eg 1 second).

If you're running 200 queries (from client-side code, not from a stored proc), then no matter how much data goes in each query, you will get 200 round-trips

Normal latency for the other end of the world is around half a second I believe - so for 200 entities retrieved separately, about 100 seconds.

Those numbers don't quite match yours, so there may be even higher latency (depends on all sorts of network factors). I would normally look for query/lookup overhead on the database server (assuming there is an indexing issue), but you've already mentioned that locally there is no significant overhead (presumably with the same data?).

Comment: yeah, this fits with the numbers we are seeing.  Thanks.

Comment: What if it's a single query... but it performs wildly differently when executing remotely vs while RDP'd to the server

Comment: @mmcrae you literally mean one single SQL statement, (one SELECT keyword, one FROM keyword, etc)? If so, that sounds like a query that returns a lot of data, and a bandwidth issue.

Comment: @Tao - that's right literally one SELECT/FROM (and 2 JOIN's). It only returns 900 rows tho...

Answer (score 4):

You're noticing network *latency*.

There needs to be at least one round-trip with the server each time you make a query.

If the server is "far", i.e. 500ms ping, that means at minimum one second of latency per query. This is uncompressible - even if the query returns no rows, that 1s hit will happen.

The bandwidth of the network is an unrelated characteristic. If your bandwidth is high, you wont notice a big difference between transferring a large dataset and a small one. But both will still suffer the latency hit in exactly the same way.

I found this article has interesting (if dated) information: [It's the latency, Stupid](http://www.stuartcheshire.org/rants/Latency.html).